# Clickbank - Create products for testing (in Sandbox)

Tags: api, sandbox, product, clickbank

I am new to Clickbank.
I want to try out the API for the same.

But I am stuck in between.

Can anyone guide me through the steps to successfully create a product.

I am getting some errors

- You must make a test purchase before submiting this request.
- A footer disclaimer is required for all Pitch and Thank You pages.

Also wanted to know, like how can I setup the sandbox account?

Please help me out.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

This question was asked a very long time ago but I just happened across it and know the answers.
First, however I think anyone starting on ClickBank, technical or otherwise, will benefit from the following: https://www.clickbank.com/launch-checklist/

Now, to answer the question(s):

**Test Purchase:**
• Can't do this without creating a product first
• To create a product you do the following:

1. Login to the account
2. Click: Vendor Settings -> My Products
3. On this page locate the list of ADD NEW buttons & Click Product
4. The product editor pretty well walks you through the process
   AND now for the test purchase.
   That process is described here: https://support.clickbank.com/hc/en-us/articles/360036958431-How-do-I-test-a-payment-link-

**Footer/disclaimer:**
This is what is known as the ClickBank Trust Badge currently, (not sure about 9years ago).
It's a little  element that you copy and paste into your webpage, after configuring what you want it to look like & where you want it to be, from the available options.
To find and set it up:

1. Login to the account
2. Click Vendor Settings -> My Site
3. Scroll down to the section with the title "ClickBank Trust Badge - Injection Code"
4. If you like the default setup you can copy what's in the Javascript Snippet field
5. If you want to change where it's located and colors click the Configure Settings button (not going to describe everything here as it's pretty straight forward as well)

**ClickBank APIs**
Last, you mentioned wanting to use the ClickBank API, which I happen to know very well. However, the documentation for it is also actually pretty good so let me start off with that:

- [General ClickBank API documentation](https://support.clickbank.com/hc/en-us/articles/220376527-ClickBank-APIs)
- Additionally each APIs primary endpoint is self documenting. Additionally this documentation tends to be the most relevant for a programmer
- Example of self documenting endpoint: https://api.clickbank.com/rest/1.3/orders2

So, it's worth noting the following that are required to use the API:

- You must have an HTTP header of "Authorization" and it must be set to both of the API keys for an account.
- Both keys refers to the API- "Clerk Key" as well as the DEV- "Developer Key"
- Enter them both, separated by a colon ":" as the value of the Authorization key with the DEV- key first (DEV-A23478C...:API-IA23456...)
- You must also use the correct HTTP request type for the query you are wanting to make (the only two that are utilized are GET and POST)

Examples:(NOTE: ACCOUNT_NAME_HERE is the ClickBank "nickname" or account name)

- Single transaction: `https://api.clickbank.com/rest/1.3/orders2/RECEIPT_NUMBER_HERE`
- List transactions by date range and specific account: `https://api.clickbank.com/rest/1.3/orders2/list?vendor=ACCOUNTNAME_HERE&startDate=2021-12-11&endDate=2021-12-14`
- Count of transactions by date range: `https://api.clickbank.com/rest/1.3/orders2/count/?vendor=ACCOUNT_NAME_HERE&startDate=2022-01-01&endDate=2022-01-01`
- Monetary value of transactions by date range: `https://api.clickbank.com/rest/1.3/quickstats/count/?account=ACCOUNT_NAME_HERE&startDate=2022-02-01&endDate=2022-02-10`
- Sending shipping data for physical products (POST): `https://api.clickbank.com/rest/1.3/shipping2/shipnotice/4NVXUFNW?item=2&date=2018-08-14&carrier=UPS&tracking=1NH323452345WODFS&comments=Test%20again%20comment%20with%20spaces10%20receipt=4NVXUFNW`